# When I run firebase serve --only hosting,functions hosting doesn't work

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I cannot emulate hosting and functions locally in the same time. Only functions works.

```
node -v
v10.15.3

firebase -V
6.9.0
```

When I run `firebase serve --only hosting,functions` I got:

```
✔  functions: Using node@10 from host.
✔  functions: Emulator running at http://localhost:5001
```

Only functions start to emulate. And a web page doesn't work. By the way the default port is 5000.

When I run `firebase serve` I got:

```
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: public
✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
```

and the same I got when I run: `firebase serve --only hosting` and then a web page works good but it doesn't have access to functions that provide an API for this web page.

I expected that when I run `firebase serve --only hosting,functions` both the hosting and the functions will start to emulate on the same port. It used to work before when I used a version 4.x of firebase-tools

Comment: Perhaps today's 6.9.1 will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a regression in firebase-tools 6.9.0. Downgrade as temporary fix.
`npm i -g firebase-tools@6.8.0`
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1242

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. You saved me hours of searching.